# mode switch and intilization of reliance Huawei 3G card

Tags: embedded-linux, 3g

i'm trying to connect reliance Huawei card on linux system ..........
but mode switch is not happening ,showing error

--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such device
sh: /dev/ttyUSB2: No such device

i added mode switch file as below

DefaultVendor=0x230d
DefaultProduct=0x0007
TargetVendor=0x230d
TargetProduct=0x0007
TargetClass=0xff
Configuration=3

CheckSuccess=20
MessageContent="55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"

but same error and light on card also not blinking........if you have any idea please share with me i have to connect that 3G card

Answer (score 1):

1. On Ubuntu 10.04 Go to `System/Administration` and click `Update Manager`. Check for updates and install it.
2. Then click on `Application` and open `Ubuntu Software Center`. Search for `wvdial` and install it.
3. Open `System/Preferences` and open `Network Connections`. Click `Mobile Broadband` then `Add` then `Forward`.
4. `Select country` as India then `Forward`.
5. Check on `I can`t find my provider and i wish to enter it manually`and In`Provider`type Reliance and click`Forward'.
6. Type in `Selected plan APN` as `rcomnet` without quotes and click `Forward` and Then click `Apply'.
7. In `Editing Reliance connection 1` check `Connect automatically` and click `Apply'. 
   Restart Your computer and plugged in  Reliance 3G card.

It will detect it in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Does it get detected.Does lsusb show you atleast one Huawei device? Did you run modeswtich as root? Why are you trying to set both the default and target product id s SAME? In that case no switch will happen.I too have the Reliance 3G card Huawei EC150. I didn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 plugged in the modem and it will detect automatically after few seconds.

1. Click on **network icon** on top right side besides **volume icon**.
2. Click **VPN connections/configure VPN...**
3. In **Network Connections**. Click **Mobile Broadband** then **Add**.
4. Under **Create a connection for this mobile broadband device**.  Select your device from dropdown. Click **continue**.
5. Select your country. Click **continue**.
6. Select your provider. Click **continue**.
7. Again click **continue**
8. Then **apply**. Then **save**.
   Click on the Connection name under **network icon** and now connected.